# Too Many Connections w/ Laravel 4 and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4, database-connection

I have a question about handling multiple DB connections in Laravel 4.1. 
Say I have one DB host with 3 DBs on that host

eg:

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'DB_1',
        'username'  => $_ENV['MYSQL_USER'],
        'password'  => $_ENV['MYSQL_PASS'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'mysql2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'DB_2',
        'username'  => $_ENV['MYSQL_USER'],
        'password'  => $_ENV['MYSQL_PASS'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'mysql3' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'DB_3',
        'username'  => $_ENV['MYSQL_USER'],
        'password'  => $_ENV['MYSQL_PASS'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Should I be making 3 different connections to those DBs?

Or should I simply have one connection and in each model specify the table name 
to something like:

```
public $table = "DB_2.table_name";
```

The reason I ask, is that I have noticed that I it is easier to exhaust the 
database connections as it creates a new DB connection when ever it needs to 
connect to a different database.

I know both will work, but I'm interested in what is considered to be "best practice" in this sort of situation.

Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify to the table, not the DB implementation.

I'm not a big fan of the 'feature' that allows cross DB querying on MySQL between DB's on the same server.  This is what would allow the thing you mention.

- If you change the name of your db you'll need to refactor your table names in your code.
- If you create a test db like `table_name_test` to test your code or a db modification, you'll have to modify all your tables tames in your code each time you jump between db's vs. just editing the config file.
- What if you move to a differnt DB technology without DB names (one Db per server/fuile, you'll need to refactor your table  name properties in each class)
- It leads down the dark, tempting yet vile path of cross db queries like `select * from db1.foo f Join db2.bar b on b.id = f.id;`.  Congratulations you just turned your 2 dbs into actually one big db that might not run outside MySQL

Also, even though you're specifying three connections, you're probably not making a connection and using all three at once... I hope.  If you do use all 3 connection per request to you laravel app/site saving 2 connections is probably, micro optimization.

Comment: Yes I think you're absolutely right. 

Ultimately, we need to re-design our data model so that we never have to make multiple DB connections for one work flow - and especially in the case of a single query. 

Until then, I need to do something that keeps the system from overloading. The issue I have is when we have a lot of concurrent requests being processed. This results in at most 3 connections per request - which can degrade performance with high traffic.

Comment: @Gimli there is no way in PDO (assuming you're using that in laravel) to 'switch' db's on the same connection.  Once a dsn is passed to a constructor, it's set.  The DSN should have the db specified.  If you try to use the db name in the $table you could get requests that look like: `select * from DB1.DB2.footable`.

Comment: @Gimili of course, using manually built queries you can do this if you're not using an orm or DQL.

Comment: Yeah, what I ended up doing is changing the table name in the model to include the database. As you stated, this is susceptible to failures if we switch from MySQL or even change DB names (which is not likely). However, I believe that we will be re-designing our data model so that this issue can be avoided.

I am selecting this as the acceptable answer as I feel it lists all the things to consider in my circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This code made the trick for me when I needed.

```
Config::set('database.default', 'database_name');
```

In your case, replace the **database_name** with the ones you may need. I call it in the controller each time I see a need to make the switch. Before a query, for exemple.

I don't know if is the ***best way ever*** to do it, but it worked for me and I thought it worth sharing! =D

Comment: while this may work, I'm not sure making database connections in a controller is good practice. However, I'm not so sure opening and closing connections on the fly would be the most performant thing either. Especially if queries to multiple databases need to be done. Then in the worst case, you'd still need 3 separate DB connections.